# PHP Replace entire sentence from string

Tags: php, string, replace, sentence

str_replace only let's me replace words.

The sentence i'm searching for is:

```
[TD="align: left"]".$num."[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]
```

And I need to replace it with:

```
[TD="align: left"]".$num."[/TD] [TD="align: left"]".$uid"[/TD]
```

The thing im searching is in a variable called $newres

I've tried str_replace but as said above it only lets me replace a word at a time, I looked into making them an array but that won't work because there are multiple

> [TD="align: left"][/TD]

in the string

Thanks!

Comment: It's just some BB code.

Comment: Yeah @h2ooooooo, I see that now, I was thinking too far ahead.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong with the escaping when using `str_replace`. `echo str_replace(" Foo Bar ", " ", "Hello Foo Bar World");` works perfectly fine and is not just "words"...

Comment: Her is my code `$newres = str_replace('[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]', '[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"]'.$uid.'[/TD]', $restext); `

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$q='[TD="align: left"]3[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]';
$q .='[TD="align: left"]33[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]';
$num=3;
$uid=6;
$w=str_replace('[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]','[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"]'.$uid.'[/TD]',$q);

var_dump($q,$w);
```

output:

```
string '[TD="align: left"]3[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD][TD="align: left"]33[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]' (length=97)

string '[TD="align: left"]3[/TD] [TD="align: left"]6[/TD][TD="align: left"]33[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]' (length=98)
```

Comment: Not sure what that gives. `uid` is a string `num` is a number. Both are already set.

Comment: `$q='[TD="align: left"]3[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]';
      $q .='[TD="align: left"]33[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]';

      $w=str_replace('[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]','[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"]'.$uid.'[/TD]',$q);

      var_dump($q,$w);` uid is lol num is 3

Comment: $q='[TD="align: left"]3[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]';
$q .='[TD="align: left"]33[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]'; 
$num=3;
$uid="string";
$w=str_replace('[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]','[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"]'.$uid.'[/TD]',$q);
var_dump($q,$w); output:string '[TD="align: left"]3[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD][TD="align: left"]33[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]' (length=97)

string '[TD="align: left"]3[/TD] [TD="align: left"]string[/TD][TD="align: left"]33[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]' (length=103)